# How to find coordinates with an offset in Xarray?

Tags: python-xarray

I have the following DataArray `da_conc`:

```
<xarray.DataArray (z: 160, time: 745500)>
array([[  8.100153e-05,   9.084830e-05,   8.815896e-05, ...,   1.136741e-05,
      1.088270e-05,   1.127361e-05],
   [  1.448712e+01,   1.505478e+01,   1.504403e+01, ...,   5.473790e-01,
      5.625886e-01,   5.521512e-01],
   [           nan,            nan,            nan, ...,   1.515498e-02,
      1.276185e-02,   1.383076e-02],
   ..., 
   [           nan,            nan,            nan, ...,            nan,
               nan,            nan],
   [           nan,            nan,            nan, ...,            nan,
               nan,            nan],
   [           nan,            nan,            nan, ...,            nan,
               nan,            nan]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * z        (z) float64 0.01008 0.02016 0.03024 0.04031 0.05039 0.06047 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-09-16T07:00:00 2014-09-16T07:00:01...
```

I masked some elements with `where` like this:

```
da_conc.where( da_conc.round() == cut )
```

to get:

[image]

But I actually need to know the values that are not in z but in z-25, where z contains all the z-coordinates of the non-null values found before. In other words, I want to know the values that are 25 cm away from the curve in the (manipulated) Figure above.

I was expecting something like this to work:

```
zcoord = da_conc.where( da_conc.round() == cut ).coords['z']
da_conc.sel( z = zcoord.round(2) == ( zcoord.round(2) - 25 ) )
```

Any help to sort this out is welcome. =)

**EDITED #1:**

I realized that would be something analogous to `shift` but instead of moving the data, I want to find the data at the new coordinates.

**EDITED #2:**

[@ocefpaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918583/ocefpaf?tab=profile) created this Gist to shed some light on the problem:

[isolines.ipynb](https://gist.github.com/ocefpaf/c8b428a1eab82a9d7dac38e523d64be7)

And here is a snapshot of his Notebook (Thanks @ocefpaf!):

```
z = np.linspace(0, 1.6, 160)
time = pd.date_range(start='2014-09-16T07:00:00', periods=745, freq='S')

data = np.random.rand(z.size, time.size) * 5

ds = xr.DataArray(data, coords=dict(z=z, time=time), dims=['z', 'time'])

z0 = np.random.rand(time.size)

z, time, data = np.broadcast_arrays(z[:, None], time[None, :], data)

z25 = z0+0.25
```

I wanted to know if I can find the data at the z25 coordinates using `Xarray`.

Comment: Your question is not complete enough to help us understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you please provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @jhamman I added a new figure showing what I want to achieve. Let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Its still not particularly clear. Can you construct an array of z coordinates that you'd like to select? I'm not really sure what you mean by `z-25`.

Comment: @jhamman, _at_ocefpaf created an example. Please see EDITED #2.